# iOS: Having usernames with Firebase authorization

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, firebase

I'm new to Firebase and don't really understand the rules section. I want to have a Sign up that requires the user to enter a Username, Email, and Password to create an account. Both the Username and Email must not already be in use. Then for the login the Username is used to login as well as the password. Any help would be appreciated. If you could point me in the direction of some tutorials I would appreciate it but if you could help me yourself I would appreciate it even more. Please keep in mind that Firebase has changed and I am using Firebase 3.2.1. .

I was getting help from someone who advised me to put the following code in the "Rules" section of Firebase:

```
{
"rules" : {
"$id" : {
  "username" : {
    ".write":"!data.exists()"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

When I asked for an explanation they did not answer me. If this is correct and fits my needs please explain it to me. If not may you help me correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to learn it is by trying to understand the [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) section, it does explain it very well, probably better than you will find any other place online. You should try and take a look at it again and see if you can make sense of it. Also, try using the simulator, it's a really powerful feature that might help you understand things a bit better.

But basically, the rules you posted means that `your-firebase.firebaseio.com/someID/username`
can only be written to if it does not already exist.